# In Firebird, how to aggregate the first N rows?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I would like to do something like this:

```
CNT=2;

//[edit]
select avg(price) from (
  select first :CNT p.Price
  from Price p
  order by p.Date desc
);
```

This does not work, Firebird does not allow `:cnt` as a parameter to FIRST.  I need to average the first CNT newest prices.  The number 2 changes so it can not be hard-coded.

This can be broken out into a FOR SELECT loop and break when a count is reached.  Is that the best way though?  Can this be done in a single SQL statement?

Creating the SQL as a string and running it is not the best fit either.  It is important that the database compile my SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use CTE, you can do it directly:

```
select avg(price) from (
  select first :cnt p.Price
  from Price p
  order by p.Date desc
);
```

Comment: Firebird rejects this with "Token unknown" and points to the `:` before the variable cnt.  In other words, it does not accept a variable as a parameter to `FIRST`.

Comment: The `:variable` will work only in PSQL, obviously. Else you cannot define variable. Or alternatively you can use parameters based on your provider. I.e. in .NET you can write `select first @cnt ...` and define parameter in `FbCommand`.

Comment: I see it now, the manual says that FIRST accepts "Any expression evaluating to an integer." http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-first-skip.  Also, I should use ROWS instead for SQL compliance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-dml.html#fblangref25-dml-select-cte) to select data before calculate average.

See example below:

```sql
with query1 as (
  select first 2 p.Price
  from Price p
  order by p.Date desc
)

select avg(price) from query1
```

Comment: nice try, true I'm really enjoying the CTEs too .. however, you hard-coded the 2 though.  I don't know 2; it is a variable.